# Kubuntu with splotchy fonts in gtk apps

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, gtk, kde4

In Kubuntu I occasionally get splotchy fonts in gtk applications.

Splotchy-ness can range from slightly annoying to completely unreadable.

As far as I can tell, the problem only occurs in gtk apps.

Below is an example screenshot of Chromium. The text drawn by gtk in the widgets (etc) is blotchy, and the bit of text below that, drawn by webkit, is fine.

[image: Web browser screenshot]

And below is a screenshot of my kde-gtk settings. The settings are at their defaults, with the oxygen-gtk widget style and the "use KDE fonts in GTK+ applications" selection checked.

[image: Settings screenshot]

Usually, I can fix the fonts by tweaking the font settings and then returning them to default, but that is not working today, and I would like to find a permanent fix.

Even the "use another font" option is not working with various other fonts chosen  --  they are all splotchy.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue.  Do you have this problem with recent versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: I have not had this problem for years. At the time, I think I switched to a different DE to solve the problem.